# How can I access documentation from the Workbench?

Tags: workbench, documentation

In Mathematica there is a hot key for searching words (that your cursor is within or adjacent to) in the documentation center, is there a way to do this from the Workbench instead of having to first switch back to Mathematica?

Comment: [apparently, we can't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700947/wolfram-workbench-and-mathematica-help-system). would be nice if someone has a way though, that's the main problem I have with workbench.

Comment: For this reason (and others) I use the frontend to write packages (with `AutoGeneratePackage` set) and use the WB only for the other functionalities it offers. I've found the FE to be more useful than the WB for editing.

Comment: @R.M So you edit nb files and generate packages from there? How do you format your code? I find large pieces of code awfully hard to read in the nb interface.

Comment: @sebhofer Don't you use code cells? The reason I don't like to use the frontend is because of the 1-step undo.

Comment: just a quick note: you do not need to be "adjacent to" a word (to call the doc center), you can be "inside" the word also.

Comment: @Mike In fact I don't, I might try that in the future. Then again I don't like the frontend for various reasons. I still find it a shame that Wolfram doesn't invest more in the development of a decent GUI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to [@acl's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700947/wolfram-workbench-and-mathematica-help-system), I found the hot key combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>, which launches the browser and navigates to the *Mathematica* documentation website.

[image]